# Custom WPF control properties display value format

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, customization

I want to create custom control in WPF...
[I followed this MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx)

I made: ImageButton : Button { ... }, and this is one of its properties:

```
[Description("Image Opacity."), Category("Image"), DisplayName("ImageOpacity")]
public double ImageOpacity
{
    get { return (double)base.GetValue(ImageOpacityProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(ImageOpacityProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageOpacityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageOpacity", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));
```

Everything works fine, but I can't find any info on how to make my custom properties use mask or text format (I dont know how it called) to show values like original controls do, for example:
[image]
I want to type 100 in my property and make it appear as 100% in properties panel, how to do it?

Comment: My guess is that the property grid uses string format for Opacity. Not sure if you can configure it via some attribute.